# training loss and validation loss both become 0.00000e+00 always

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, neural-network, conv-neural-network

can someone help me to resolve this why i'm getting my loss 0.0000e+00.

I've looked around that few people had the same problem but I'm not be able to fix it following same advices.

Rows are shuffled and label is already transformaned into float32. These are suggestions I've found on similar questions. Can you tell me what i'm wrong?

this problem is a classification of images having classes more than 1.

this is how i create my model

```py
def createmodel():
    pretrained = InceptionV3(input_shape=(150,150,3),
                        include_top=False,
                        weights='imagenet')
    for layer in pretrained.layers:
        layer.trainable = False  


    x = layers.Flatten()(pretrained.output)
    x = layers.Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x) 
    x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = layers.Dense(1,activation="softmax")(x)
    model = Model(pretrained.input,x)
    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(0.001),
                  loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
                  )
    return model
```

```
Epoch 1/2
10/10 [==============================] - 3s 322ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/2
10/10 [==============================] - 5s 464ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the final layer. The size should be equal to the number of classes as opposed to 1, i.e.:

```
x = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(x)
```

assuming `num_classes` is the number of the distinct classes in your data.